# WebglEarth and Touch-Support

Tags: javascript, touch, cesiumjs, webgl-earth

I'm trying to make [webglearth](http://www.webglearth.org/), which is using [cesiumjs](https://cesiumjs.org/) under the hood, work with a touch-screen. <s>So far no luck. The readme says it supports mobile devices, but I can't confirm that either.</s>

I am initializing my earth like that:

```
        var earth = new WE.map('world', {
            zoom: 1,
            altitude: 7000000,
            minAltitude: 3500000,
            maxAltitude: 20000000,
            tilting: false,
            atmosphere: false,
            sky: true,
            dragging: true
        });
```

<s>What am I doing wrong? Or has anybody any idea for a solution?</s>

---

Edit: As it turns out I've done nothing wrong and the framework is touch-able. 
There seems to be a problem with the latest chrome-version(s) that is blocking this functionality. I'll leave that question open for anybody also encountering this problem.

As the time of writing I'm using Chrome 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit).

For the NodeWebkit (nwjs) App I'm developing I fell back to Chrome 52 and it works.

Comment: I don't know webglearth, but I can at least confirm that Cesium has touch support with pinch-zoom and the like.

Comment: I also saw that and that's why I'm really confused that *webglearth* which is presumably _based on Cesium_ doesn't support such a common feature...

Comment: @emackey Is there an API-Option in Cesium to enable/disable touch? Maybe they've disabled it..

Comment: No, there's no Cesium option to disable touch support, but they could possibly have replaced Cesium mouse/touch/pointer controls completely with something homegrown.